wetness around ac drain line
For a while, my ac condensation wasn't draining properly because the drain line that was supposed to come out of the side of the house was cut flush and stucco'd over. The hvac guys helpfully blew conpressed air into the drain to find where the drain came out and in the process cleared a bit of the stucco around the pipe. After that, water seemed to be draining out.
That was about a week ago but checking up on it today, I can feel that the wall around the pipe feels quite damp. The pipe also seems to be leaking from behind the stucco (or is it concrete now that the stucco is gone?)  I checked the rooms adjacent to the pipe and I'm seeing water stains on the baseboards that I didn't notice before because there was an armchair in that corner. On the other side is a closet where I also saw similar stains. These stains feel dry to me, but could there still be water inside my walls that haven't drained? What would be the best thing to do at this point?
https://ibb.co/album/cKPYjc
Images of the pipe and the baseboards. The brown spot I'm pointing at is what feels wet.

Is that a piece of new pipe?  Seems to stick out too far to be covered with stucco.

Did they fit the extension to the inside or outside dimension of the existing pipe? If it was inside, the extension is leaking.

@JACK yes it's a new piece. The hvac guys inserted it there when they cleared out the stucco. I guess they probably had it stick out far so I had the option to cut it myself

@DelphicOracle that I'm not sure but the original piece was flush and didn't seem like it had room around it to fit in something to the outer diameter.

Therefore the new pipe is inside the old pipe and it is leaking or there is a break somewhere else along the old pipe.

I think that is the case. I glued it today with pvc cement and it is still leaking from around the pipe, at the wall.

You'll need to chip away the stucco with a small cold chisel or concrete nail all around the pipe and about 1/2" back. Then get a appropriate size coupling and small piece of straight pipe and glue them in place. I'd also add a 90 degree elbow pointing down to prevent anything from crawling in there. Caulk around the stucco and new coupling and pipe. You could attack this from the inside wall but then you'd have more noticeable repairs.

How deep is a stucco layer normally? With the surface layer blown off, it feels like concrete to me but I'm not too experience in that regard.

@BunniFaccie  It varies by installer, usually 3/8" over concrete and 1/2" over felt & metal mesh.  You can get a masonry drill bit and drill around the pipe to remove much of the concrete and chisel out the rest. Use care not to damage the pipe.
